# npm ci gives deprecated package warning - vue

Tags: vuejs2, dependencies

When run *npm ci* command in my Vue 2 application I got few deprecated packages error.

```
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
```

These package are not found in package.json file, but these are dependendent or requires in some packages from package-lock.json. For example, stable@1.0.8 package is required in *npm svgo* package and also svgo is dependent package on some other.
How can I fix these warnings?

Answer (score 0):

Running:

```
ng update
```

... will analyze your package.json, and will give you the commands you need to update all your dependencies.